# Adding hours after midnight today

Tags: datetime, plsql, oracle11g

Im trying to add hours to midnight of today eg: like 27 hours

I have tried various methods from the internet but am getting the trunc of the dated expected.  eg 23-nov-2022 not 23-nov-2022 03:00.   when i run it outside my pl/sql procedure/block i get the desired output

the select:

select to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MI')+hours/24,'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MI') into v_from from dual;

I need some expert assistance

Comment: What data type is `v_from`, and how are you displaying its value? You are currently adding hours to the current time, not midnight - you aren't truncating `sysdate`; and you shouldn't call `to_date()` for something that is already a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type to `SYSDATE` `TRUNC`ated back to midnight:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_from DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) + INTERVAL '27' HOUR
  INTO   v_from
  FROM   DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_from,'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MI'));
END;
/
```

or, more simply:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_from DATE;
BEGIN
  v_from := TRUNC(sysdate) + INTERVAL '27' HOUR;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_from,'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MI'));
END;
/
```

or, dynamically, with the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_from  DATE;
  v_hours NUMBER(3,0) := 27;
BEGIN
  v_from := TRUNC(sysdate) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(v_hours,'HOUR');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_from,'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MI'));
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/baotslgr)

Comment: thank you. the numstodateinterval helped me .  thank you both for the help and guidance

Answer (score 1):

Trunc `SYSDATE` to get midnight. Then add hours: 1 hour is 1/24 day so you'd add the number of hours divided by 24. Example.

```
koen>DECLARE
  2    l_date DATE;
  3    l_hours NUMBER :=  27;
  4  BEGIN
  5    l_date := TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 27/24;
  6    dbms_output.put_line('l_date is: '||TO_CHAR(l_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'));
  7  END;
  8* /
l_date is: 23-NOV-2022 03:00


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

koen>
```

The select from dual is not advised, you can just assign a variable in pl/sql using the assignment operator `:=`. The `select from dual` requires an additional context switch (invoke the sql engine from within pl/sql).

Comment: Thank you Koen,  your pl/sql block works perfectly,  when i put it in my procedure it truncates.  let me try a function

Comment: let me try putting in into a dynamic action in apex